# li tag in html shows no action when clicked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After having tried to figure out for one day why this simple piece of code is not working, I have to ask someone else because I just can't figure it out.

HTML:

```
<li><button id="button-middle" type="button"></button>
<ul id="list-middle" style="display: none;"></ul>
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button-middle').click(function () {
        $.post('file.php', {data_1: $('#select_1 option:selected').text(), data_2: $('#select_2 option:selected').text()}, function (data) {
            $('#list-middle').html(data);
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list-middle li').click(function () {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

The button is part of an ul that contains three button, this one is the middle one.
file.php just consists of a simple echo with the sent data inserted. The output is as expected (li tags in an ul), but when I click one of these li tags, nothing happens. Why is that?

Just to be super clear, here is the php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['data_1']) and isset($_POST['data_2'])) {
        $data_1 = $_POST['data-1'];
        $data_2 = $_POST['data_2'];
        echo '<li data-value="right" id="to_right"><span>&#8594;&nbsp;Von '.$data_1.' nach '.$data_2.'</span></li>
                                <li data-value="left" id="to_left"><span>&#8594;&nbsp;Von '.$data_2.' nach '.$data_1.'</span></li>
    ';
    }
```

I appreciate any help becuase after more than a day, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Have you confirmed the event is actually firing and the request being sent?

Comment: I think this was the very problem, because jquery acted as though there were no li tags to begin with, so I don't think the request was being sent in the first place. Turned out it had to do with dynamic loaded content (which I was aware of) and how to properly deal with it (which I wasn't aware of, because I have only worked with jquery for about two weeks).

Comment: That explains it. Event handlers bound literally to the elements you're interested in will not retrospectively apply to any matching elements added to the DOM after the event is bound. As the accepted answer alludes to (but doesn't really explain) the solution is to use [delegated event handling](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). In debugging events, the first thing to always check is that the event is actually firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind actions, like click actions, you should define a context (document in this case) in order to work with dynamic loaded content. Think it should work:

```
$(document).on('click','#list-middle li', function(e){ alert('test'); });
```

Comment: Thank yo so much, this did the trick! I knew that there was .on(), but I didn't quite grasp its meaning (honestly I still don't, so this will be the next thing for me to study in detail). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: You have to know, you can reduce context to a minor element. 
So you can work only with $('#list-middle').on('click', 'li',....
I Think should work :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that list itemss are added dynamically, so on click event is not attached to them. Because it fired only once on document ready.

You might try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#list-middle li', function() {
    // do something
});
```

If I recall correct, it's called Event Bubbling.

Comment: Though in this form it didn't work, the basic idea of working with .on() was the solution. Thank you!